# Terraform AWS instance with specific private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to chose the private ip of my instances but i keep getting this error:

```
Error: Error creating ENI: InvalidParameterValue: Address is in subnet's reserved address range status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxxxx
with aws_network_interface.my-instance-nic
on main.tf line 222, in resource "aws_network_interface" "my-instance-nic":

    resource "aws_network_interface" "my-instance-nic" {
```

The above is when i try to create a NIC with my priviate IP. the same happens when I try to use `private_ip` of `aws_instance` resource directly.

Answer (score 0):

my bad, I didn't know AWS they reserve the first, second and third IPs from all subnets (apart from network address and broadcast). I found answer here:

[How do I assign an EC2 instance to a fixed IP address within a subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212709/how-do-i-assign-an-ec2-instance-to-a-fixed-ip-address-within-a-subnet)

I didnt find it at first because i was looking for a terraform specific answer (using the error string).